# No modules found! When installing SoapySDR on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to install SoapySDR and the Airspy mini on the Raspberry Pi 3. This is relevant to everyone who wants to do the same.

When I follow the build guide and do:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make -j4
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig #needed on debian systems
SoapySDRUtil --info
```

But after doing SoapySDRUtil --info I get: No modules found! and No factories found!

After cmake .. it says: PYTHON3_INSTALL_DIR: ${prefix}//usr/lib/python3.5
SoapySDR disabled features: Python3 , python3 bindings

After running SoapySDRUtil --info it says: Install root: /usr/local
Search path: /usr/local/lib/SoapySDR/modules0.7
No modules found!

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed SoapySDRUtil? If yes, that should just mean that it is not installed in /usr/local/lib/SoapySDR/modules0.7
add its location to your PATH variable or if it is there but with a different name you could just make a symbolic link to modules0.7

Comment: I added the location of SoapySDRUtil to my PATH variable and still get the same result:   

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ PATH=~/home/pi/SoapySDR/build/SoapySDR/apps:$PATH
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ SoapySDRUtil --find
###################
##     Soapy SDR -- the SDR abstraction library     ##
##############

No devices found!